# Debug CMake Project Creation

Tags: msbuild, cmake, allegro5

I am facing a specific problem, and want advice or a way to debug it.

I am building the Allegro library from source, using: Windows 10, CMake, and Visual Studio 2015 build tools (msbuild).

Source: https://github.com/liballeg/allegro5

The problem is that when I run `cmake --build .' I am getting errors stating that the v100 toolset isn't installed, however I'm making it for Visual Studio 2015, and not 2010.  If I open up the solution, or run msbuild directly, it builds perfectly fine.

Is there a way to Debug CMake that will help me see the issue?

Failing Commands:

```
mkdir _build
pushd _build
cmake.exe ..
cmake --build .
popd
```

Error:

> "C:\Users\matthew\repos\allegro5_build\ALL_BUILD.vcxproj" (default
>   target) (1) ->
>   "C:\Users\matthew\repos\allegro5_build\ZERO_CHECK.vcxproj" (default
>   target) (2) -> (PlatformPrepareForBuild target) ->   C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\Microsoft.Cpp.Platform.targets(55,5):
>   error MSB8020: The build  tools for Visual Studio 2010 (Platform
>   Toolset = 'v100') cannot be found. To build using the v100 build
>   tools, please install Visual Studio 2010 build tools.  Alternatively,
>   you may upgrade to the current Visual Studio tools by selecting  the
>   Project menu or right-click the solution, and then selecting "Retarget
>   solution". [C:\Users\matthew\repos\allegro5
>   _build\ZERO_CHECK.vcxproj]

Working Commands:

```
mkdir _build
pushd _build
cmake.exe ..
msbuild ALLEGRO.sln
popd
```

I've also tried forcing it to Visual Studio 2015 with commands like:

```
cmake.exe -G "Visual Studio 14" ..
```

Note:  I've built my own small project with CMake and it builds correctly using CMake --build

To me it seems like something crazy with the allegro cmake build.  I have searched through the source to try and find references to v100 and MSVC_2010, but found nothing of concern.
I don't want to directly use MSBuild as a work-around because I want to include allegro with ExternalProject_Add, and that fails for the same reason as building it with cmake --build.

How can I go about solving this issue?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Debugging CMakeLists.txt](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22803607/debugging-cmakelists-txt)

Comment: Might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38869455/2799037

Comment: If you are convinced Allegro refers to v100 tools (why would they do that?), then go with the `ExternalProject_Add` approach and look for Allegro cmake files. I find https://crascit.com/2016/10/18/test-fixtures-with-cmake-ctest/ to be a clean way to use the external project feature.

Comment: Your answer could be here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33380128/visual-studio-2015-command-line-retarget-solution - it could be as simple an old `.vcxproj` file referring to `v100` toolset. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem with another library (Zipper, a C++ wrapper around minizip). I was also using CMake and ExternalProject_Add in particular. Exact same error. I spent a lot of time researching the issue. I found a similar problem with another project using [Gyp](https://gist.github.com/equalsraf/4685f7aef022a36c26d5) (have a look at the "Known issue" section). For me, the error was occurring during the install target. Changing

> BUILD_COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} --build . --config Release

to

> BUILD_COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} --build . --config Release --target install
>     INSTALL_COMMAND ""

fixed the issue. Not sure what the problem is. It seems like the default install command CMake uses in an ExternalProject picks the wrong toolset somehow...

Comment: Thanks for this information!  This didn't solve my issue, as it's not in the install step but in the build step.  However, this is pointing to it being something wrong with CMake, Visual Studio 2015, and/or building on Windows 10.
Another group having the same issue:  https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp/issues/679