# Control Windows SDK Version from msbuild command-line?

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, visual-studio-2019

As specified in the [VS2019 docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-command-line-reference?view=vs-2019), we have the msbuild command-line option `-property:name=value` / `-p:name=value`.

I found I [can use this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33386141/197229) for instance to override the platform toolset: `/p:PlatformToolset=v140` but I cannot find either:

1. A full list of the allowed properties
2. How to find the property name against each option in Project Properties dialog in VS, e.g. where is it documented that "Platform Toolset" is controlled /p:PlatformToolset?

[image]

I am specifically looking to set "Windows SDK Version" from the command-line.

Answer (score 0):

> A full list of the allowed properties

You could read this document: [Platform toolset](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/how-to-modify-the-target-framework-and-platform-toolset?view=msvc-160) and [MSBuild internals for C++ projects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/msbuild-visual-cpp-overview?view=msvc-160)

> How to find the property name against each option in Project Properties dialog in VS, e.g. where is it documented that "Platform Toolset" is controlled /p:PlatformToolset?

You can open vcxproj file as notepad to read them.
[image]

Comment: Oh, so the names of the Xml elements is literally what you pass as command-line arguments? Is this guaranteed?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure. `-p` means that the properties in `<PropertyGroup>`

Comment: My question is actually about the Windows SDK version, so I think that would be `WindowsTargetPlatformVersion`?

Comment: Yes, the <WindowsTargetPlatformVersion> is Windows SDK version.